# Lazy Loading in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I created a lazy loading route for a contact view. When I click on the contact chunk file, the corresponding contact is created. But, routing is directing into redirectUrl.
[image]

I added the routing like this, but it is not loading and loading ** condition for path.

```js
{ path: 'contact', loadChildren: './contact/contact.module#ContactModule' }
```

I am using Angular CLI version 1.7.4.

Comment: it is not redirect to contact

Comment: could you please post the code

Comment: Have you tried removing the `./` from your route and just using `loadChildren: 'contact/contact.module#ContactModule'`?

Comment: can you create a project in stackblitz and add the link here

Comment: did u try running "ng serve --aot" ?

Comment: Using ng serve --aot , it is working.Thank you all